# Nothing returned when running .tables after tables supposedly are created

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask to build a Python web-app following this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71EU8gnZqZQ&t=861s). It is outdated. I am on the step where I access the Python3 console and run:

```
>>> from app import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

This does not work and I get an error:

> RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

Running the following should solve it:

```
>>> from app import app, db
>>> app.app_context().push()
>>> db.create_all()
```

It seems to work but when I run:

```
sqlite3 database.db
sqlite> .tables
```

Nothing is returned. I then tried `sqlite3 ./database.db` instead but `.tables` still returned nothing. I am using up to date versions of everything. My code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'password'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

@JohnGordons mentioned I was running from the wrong directory. My tree:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── database.db
│   ├── instance
│   │   └── database.db
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── app.cpython-310.pyc
│   ├── static
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── templates
│    
│       └── home.html
├── __pycache__
│   └── app.cpython-310.pyc
├── README.md
└── requirements.txt
```

I was running SQLite3 on database.db in "app" folder (as that is the database file I made). I don't remember creating an "instance" directory with a database.db file. How did that get there, as when running .tables it returns the output I expected?

Comment: It looks like the application is using a `database.db` file in a different directory than the one you used in the sqlite3 shell.  Try `sqlite3 /database.db`  This will tell sqlite3 to use the database file in the **root directory**.  The command you used before looked in the **current directory**.

Comment: @JohnGordon That's because I ran that from the directory that my database.db file is. I'll add my tree into the original post for extra clarity